# Wordpress navigation add/remove class not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress, nav

I'm trying to add an active state to my 'li's' in wordpress, and I can see in the dev tools that it's adding the class but then it just disappears. Am I missing something obvious? It's a Wordpress nav. Thanks!

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu-nav a').click(function() {
        $('#menu-nav a').removeClass('activeNav');
        $(this).addClass('activeNav');
    });
});
```

Comment: Do these links lead to other pages or are they links within a single page?

Comment: @ChrisHerbert They link to other pages, so does that mean that I need to use the #href's?

Comment: Changes made to the DOM in javascript do not persist when you move to a different page.  I would use WordPress's native menu system, which will automatically add an active class to the li of the page that you are currently on.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris mentioned, it wouldn't be surprising if your links that are being clicked are redirecting to another page, causing the entire page to reload. If you'd like to prevent the anchors from redirecting to another page, you can use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu-nav a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // this will cancel the action of the link
    $('#menu-nav a').removeClass('activeNav');
    $(this).addClass('activeNav');
  });
});
```